# Forget about the previous click when I click on a new object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a system where you can create a house and some people. When you have created the house, and you then click on it, some information will appear. You'll also get the opportunity to delete the house.

However, the system will now forget the previous click if you click on a new house. Therefor both of the houses that I've clicked on, will be removed.

You can test it in the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Adnaves/t8TKc/)

It all happend inside my click function:

```
  var objHouse = $('#' + oHouse.id)

  objHouse.click(function(){

    $('#WindowDisplayCarInfo').hide();
    $('#WindowDisplayPersonInfo').hide();
    $("#WindowDisplayHouseInfo").show();

    $('#ShowId').text("ID: " + this.id);
    $('#ShowStreetName').text("Street Name: " + oHouse.StreetName);
    $('#ShowNumber').text("Number: " + oHouse.Number);
    $('#ShowInhabitants').empty();
    $('#ShowMaxInhabitants').text("Max inhabitants: " + oHouse.MaxPeople);


    for(var i = 0; i < oHouse.aPeople.length; i++)
    {
    $('#ShowInhabitants').append("<br />" 
                               +"<br />" + "ID: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].id
                               +"<br />" + "Name: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].Name
                               +"<br />" + "Last Name: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].Lastname
                               +"<br />" + "Age: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].Age
                               +"<br />" + "Gender: " + oHouse.aPeople[i].sGender
                               );
    }   

        $('.DeleteHouse').click(function()
        {
            $(objHouse).children().each(function(){
                $(this).appendTo($('#container')).css({"top":"" , "left":"", "display":"block"});
            });

            $(objHouse).remove();                  
            $("#WindowDisplayHouseInfo").hide();
        });
});
```

}

(It start at line 130 in the JSFIDDLE.)

Hope that you can teach me a trick or two. :-)

Comment: I have no idea what or how you did it but you managed to make `objHouse` have multiple values as a variable. Console.log it out. And every time you click delete every box that has ever been selected will be consoled out. It makes no sense Ive tried erasing the variable... just getting the ID but nothing works. I think its because you have everything in the `CreateHouseInLayout` function

Comment: Oh yeah, I see. I've tried logget it out. This looks wierd. I didn't think that it was this bad :p

Comment: I came up with a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isnt good practice but after like 30 min its all I could come up with. It just pulls the ID from the box in the upper right and deletes only the selected box. The "bad practice" is probably the substr part. To make it slightly better you may want to utilize `indexOf()` to find the start of the ID not just the integer 4 incase the structure of that ID box ever changes.

```
$('.DeleteHouse').click(function()
{
    $(objHouse).children().each(function(){
        $(this).appendTo($('#container')).css({"top":"" , "left":"", "display":"block"});
    });
    var currentID = $("#ShowId").html().substr(4);
    console.log(currentID);
    $("#"+currentID).remove();  
    $("#WindowDisplayHouseInfo").hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t8TKc/3/

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for putting so much time into helping me. But yeah, this might not be the best solution. But it's one way of solving my problem. I'll try reading about indexOf(), and see if I can get it to work with that in the future. Thank you very much for your time sir!